# Fail2Ban, ban all ip except for myself

Tags: ssh, ip, fail2ban

I am trying to whitelist ONE ip (myself) from accessing a device via ssh. How do I ban ALL ip except myself (1 ip that i am using?)

Context: I saw there are 500 ip attacks yesterday, I just wanna make my device safe.

---

---

---

I have this, is this working??

```
(base) abc@myub:~$ sudo ufw status


Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW   172.xx.xx.xxxx
```

Comment: If you have an open port to the internet (and especially port 22), your device is never completely safe - sorry.

Comment: what would be the best way to keep myself safe? I probably need ssh to my device once in a while (i.e., I don't need it to be open 24/7).

Comment: Not having port 22 open would be a good start. Moving SSH to another port will reduce the attack surface - but still nothing is 100% safe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, what usually port number is valid for ssh? Sorry for this noobie question

Comment: You can use any port you like - keeping it a secret will (theoretically and probably marginally) increase safety.

Comment: thx for the tips

Comment: Instead of using SSH, use something like [OpenVPN](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-openvpn) instead.  Then you can keep all those ports closed (except port 1194), it uses certificates for connecting instead of logins so someone trying to hack in never gets a login screen.  And you can use SSH through the VPN just fine.

Comment: Can't you just firewall port 22 and allow access only from that one IP? Seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: how do I do that, do I configure that through the router?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to use fail2ban for that.

Instead, use the firewall to block all other IPs from the port you are using to connect on.

Assuming ufw is set up to deny all already,

`sudo ufw allow from XXX to any port YYYY`

Where XXX is your IP and YYYY is the port you are connecting on

***But before you do this, make sure you have an alternate way to connect in case your IP changes***

Comment: Please see the update above, is this working?

(base) abc@myub:~$ sudo ufw status
    
    
    Status: active
    To                         Action      From
    --                         ------      ----
    22                         ALLOW   172.xx.xxx.xxx

Comment: That looks right but you probably shouldn't give out your ip address. Try sshing in on a duplicate session, and again, make sure you have a backup plan in case your ip changes.

Answer (score 0):

As for fail2ban blocking everything, you can surely switch the mode of jail (chain or its blocktype) to DROP or REJECT all IPs and unban yourself with http-knocking or port-knocking.

Here is an example jail for iptables/nftables and http-knocking:  https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/2df58c5281facd73e73778a734a90f7d4fe95468/config/jail.conf#L911-L925

You can also use something like port-knocking without fail2ban, e. g. with knockd:
https://joost.vunderink.net/blog/2015/05/07/hiding-your-sshd-with-ufw-and-knockd-on-ubuntu/